# Some wrong when I use Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let $x_n = \sqrt n $,
$\forall p \in \mathbb{N} ,\forall ε>0,\exists N=[\frac{p^2}{ε^2}]+1,n>N$,
$|x_{n+p}-x_n|=\frac{p}{\sqrt{n+p}+\sqrt n}<\frac{p}{\sqrt n}<ε$

So the sequence$\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence? Then the sequence is convergent?
But the sequence $\{x_n\}$, in fact, is divergent.

Comment: $\frac{p}{\sqrt{n}}$ becomes "arbitraty" since you have $\forall p\in\mathbb{N}$ before. This violates the Cauchy criterion.